# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy') when using Svelte and egjs-grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, sveltekit

I'm attempting to run a toy example of egjs-grid for Svelte, and I get the titular error when I attempt to run it. My code is very simple:

```html
<script>
    import { JustifiedGrid } from "@egjs/svelte-grid";
  
    const gap = 5;
    const defaultDirection = "end";
    const rowRange = 0;
    const columnRange = [1,8];
    const sizeRange = [200,1000];
    const isCroppedSize = false;
    const displayedRow = -1;
  </script>
  
  <JustifiedGrid
    class="container"
    {defaultDirection}
    {gap}
    {rowRange}
    {columnRange}
    {sizeRange}
    {isCroppedSize}
    {displayedRow}
  >
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </JustifiedGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an SSR issue. The component gets rendered in the server first and it can't find the destroy property of something which only exists in the browser.

This can be solved by adding a browser guard, like so:

```html
<script>
    import { browser } from "$app/env";
    import { JustifiedGrid } from "@egjs/svelte-grid";
  
    const gap = 5;
    const defaultDirection = "end";
    const rowRange = 0;
    const columnRange = [1,8];
    const sizeRange = [200,1000];
    const isCroppedSize = false;
    const displayedRow = -1;
</script>

{#if browser}
    <JustifiedGrid
        class="container"
        {defaultDirection}
        {gap}
        {rowRange}
        {columnRange}
        {sizeRange}
        {isCroppedSize}
        {displayedRow}
    >
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
        <div class="item">8</div>
        <div class="item">9</div>
        <div class="item">10</div>
    </JustifiedGrid>
{/if}
```

However, this solution is ugly and not idiomatic. The library author should probably strive to make it work with SSR (maybe you can consider contributing to said library!).

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. I can look into contributing later, but it looks like your solution doesn't work? I just tried it and the page is stuck infinitely loading.

Comment: Huh, it definitely does work for me on a new SvelteKit skeleton project. I literally copy-pasted my `index.svelte`. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you. Maybe I could help you if you give me more details.